# What future consequences are possible from a Standard Visitor visa refusal?

Tags: visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, bangladeshi-citizens

Well, I was supposed to visit UK on 20th-22nd July this year to participate in a competition / conference as an undergraduate student from Bangladesh. I submitted my application on 18th June but it was refused:

> As Evidence of your circumstances you have submitted *bank name* statement in your father's name... for account number ***** shows a balance of ***BDT (around 2,500USD) after a deposit of ***BDT (around 1,600USD). There is no evidence of the source of these funds. You have provided electricity bills but no evidence of your father's employment or income. I am not satisfied that the documents you have provided evidence your circumstances and this lends me to doubt that you are seeking entry only for the purpose and duration stated. I am not satisfied that you are genuine visitor and will leave the the United Kingdom at the end of your visit.

I should've probably added another document stating my father's occupation and that he will bear my costs. However, it is general knowledge in my country that a father will very likely bear the cost of his children. Probably not so in the UK. Incidentally, I have searched the term `Visa refused for source of funds` from a private window and the first page of Google results are all related to UK visas.

What pains me most is that this letter was signed on 23rd July even though I submitted my application a month earlier. Which means that for the whole time they didn't process my application. They could have called/contacted me if they needed any further documents. However they didn't which, I think, means they tend to reject applications more than they accept and do not care much about the applicants.

However, I will not reapply for a visa as the event in which I was due to participate is already over.

I was wondering what the future consequences of this refusal might be. I have previously visited India for a conference and stayed for 11 days.

Now that I have this smirch in my passport will it affect my future visits to other countries?

---

There were six of us. We all submitted similar documents according to my knowledge. However, only one received a visa, probably because he had visited Russia and USA. Two of us were refused and the other three are still waiting for their decisions.

Comment: They got you on "funds parking" and provenance of funds, making this question a duplicate.  See if there's anything in your question which is not already answered here and you can change/edit your question to make it unique if so

Comment: Yes, that is a similar question. But my question was, what will this have an impact on other VISA applications that I'll do in future for other countries. I do not have intentions to visit UK anytime soon. But since my UG studies are coming to an end; few other conferences in other countries I will likely have in future. How much affect this refusal will have in those applications? [things like this.]

Comment: "Summary: you can reliably assume that the USA has a file on your brother's UK history. In the absence of breach or criminal activity, there's no reason to believe an application will be refused outright. And the caveat is that a USA legal specialist will be able to examine all of your brother's materials and give you a better reading on it."
- From your answer in that thread, does my case relate to 'breach or criminal activity'?
That will probably answer my question. :)

Comment: Getting a refusal is not a breach or criminal activity. So no.

Comment: Thanks. Probably I will still be worried until I have another VISA in some country accepted. UK Immigration system is so stringent! Thanks a lot for your help. :\

Comment: One last question though. When I submitted the visa application I didn't find any article about about explaining unusual transaction or to explain the occupation of the person who is funding my travel. Are these hidden requirements? or buried somewhere where I didn't look?

Comment: Really good question!  Yes, the language is very subtle!  It's more clearly stated in law books like Gina Clayton's and MacDonald's.  Very astute of you to have spotted it.  Consider asking a completely new question.  It might be helpful to a broader audience.  Impressed!  :)

Comment: Thanks for the complements. However, since I got the refusal letter I'm not feeling that enthusiastic. Probably some other time. This is the first time I had my VISA application refused. And it was not a pleasant experience - waiting for more than a month just for a conference visa - I never thought. And 5 of 6 of us didn't receive any visa. They are not happy as well. :\

Comment: Yes, refusals can be discouraging.  On the other hand, there's an opportunity to help others avoid the same outcome IMHO

Comment: Since you say it that way. here it [is](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51849/hidden-requirements-in-uk-visa-applications)

Comment: Well done, it's a very interesting question