# UK visa to visit a partner in hospital (after prior rejection)

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, russian-citizens

I would like to apply for a UK visitor visa for 6 month in order to visit my partner who is in the hospital right now.

However, I have already applied for a visa a year ago and got declined. Here are the details:

I am from Russia and I live in Germany for almost 3 years now. I did my Masters here and now started with my PhD in January 2022. When I applied last year I said that I am going to visit my friend (we were not yet dating at that point) and that he will provide for my stay there. I have attached his bank statements, my bank statements and his invitation letter. I also said that I am finishing my masters and applying for PhD but I forgot to attach the enrollment certificate (my bad). Plus my visa was ending as I was almost done with my masters.

They declined because I didn't provide sufficient proof that I will leave the UK (the text is in the comment), which is understandable. But I am not sure if I have enough evidence now to apply again.

I would like to apply again because my partner is in the hospital and I would like to see him.

- I have started my PhD now, so I am attaching a **letter from my employer** stating that I am a PhD student, I will work on it for the next 4 years, I have a scholarship of 1400 and they expect me to be back in a week if I go to the UK.
- I will also attach my **bank statements** (rn 2 k, I don't have savings).
- My partner's family will also write a **letter of invitation** and say that I will stay with them and they will cover my expenses if my funds are insufficient.
- Possibly they could also provide a **paper from the hospital**.
- Maybe I can provide a letter from my lab colleagues and photos, that I have a **strong community ties**?

I am not sure I can provide much more. I would save more money on my account but I would like to see my partner as soon as possible. I wanted to pay extra for the application to be reviewed in 5 days.

I was also thinking to write a cover letter explaining the situation. Truthfully, I don't care to immigrate to the UK, I have a great position in Germany and I am planning to stay here and get a German passport at some point. I am happy with our long distance relationship and am not planning to marry. I don't know how to prove that to the UK immigration though.

Here is the UK visa rejection letter:

---

> [image: UK visa rejection letter]

---

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: The OP wanted us to see the letter, as the OP added the ULR of its image into comments. How is this different? We usually ask that participants include copies (redacted as this one is) of rejection letters.

Comment: I don't mind it posted there I just thought it's too much text for one post. But thank you!

Comment: Seems to be OK with the OP, @RodrigodeAzevedo. Mila, this is a question-and-answer site, and all of the relevant information should be included in the question itself. Some questions are short, some are long.

Comment: As far as I can see you have covered off all the refusal points from your previous application and the evidence you’re proposing now is *much* stronger. This question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-back-up-a-uk-visit-visa-appli might help with your cover letter. One question springs to mind that might be a (slight) red flag, which is whether you and your partner have met in person up to now? And of course there is no way to know how much Putin’s invasion of Ukraine is/will affect visa decisions for Russian citizens right now

Comment: @Mila, all users here can edit all questions and answers, those with low rep (points) on this site will need approval, those with more experience can do it themselves.

Comment: Then I will delete my comment.

Comment: @Traveller, thank you so much for the comment! And yes, I also worry about how the war will affect my application. Especially the processing time. I don't know of my application will be considered straightforward now and the 5 day processing would work. Also, yes, we met several times before in the EU, because I didn't want to reapply for the UK visa. Is this good or bad? Should I provide evidence that we met?

Comment: @Mila It looks much better if your partner has visited you so yes, I would mention in your covering letter that they have visited you X times since your relationship began. I always state how many visits I’ve made to my partner in Cuba whenever we apply for a visit visa for him. You might also consider mentioning when and how you met, how often you communicate and how (eg daily calls, messages) and if applicable, whether your partner supports you financially in any way (provide proof of the latter)

Comment: @Mila This https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55802/how-to-avoid-getting-a-visa-refusal-when-applying-for-a-uk-visitor-visa might be helpful

Answer (score 4):

**Your application will be much stronger now that you are enrolled in a PhD.**

That is assuming that you also have a visa that will allow you to stay in Germany for the duration of the PhD, or at least for several years of it. Being enrolled in a course of study gives you much stronger motivation to return to Germany after your visit to the UK.

However the rejection letter also points to you not having provided enough information about your financial situation. You need to provide bank statements and other documents to indicate what your expenses are, and how you pay for them. Primarily it's not about "do you have enough money to pay for the visit to the UK", but "Do you have enough money coming in, relative to your expenses, that paying for a visit to the UK makes financial sense?" Does your scholarship pay all your expenses? Are you doing a job in addition to your studies? Are you paying your expenses out of savings?

The letter from your partner's family stating that they will pay your expenses while in the UK will be helpful. A letter from the hospital will not be a lot of help - your partner being in hospital will not be a big factor in the decision. Anything that backs up your claim of being a student will help somewhat.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It is very informative. I do worry about the money evidence. I am not very good at saving money yet. Although it is always enough for me, I often spend my salary completely (I've moved to a new house, had to buy a lot of stuff, new computer, travelling during the summer and so on). Also, I am not officially a student at the university (it is not necessary) but in my permit it is specifically stated that I am working on my phd in this specific lab.

Comment: Also, I have only one more question: I receive most of my money from the scholarship. But translating the confirmation letter from the scholarship would be very expensive. Do you think it would be enough just to provide the letter from the head of the lab (technically my employers) stating how much money I get and that I work in their lab? As a scholarship holder, I don't have a contract in a traditional sense. It's a stupid system here in germany but I worry that it might provoke questions.

Comment: I would read what it says on the visa application notes, which I'm pretty sure will answer that question. If it doesn't, please ask a separate question on this site.

Comment: As far as I can see in the list of supporting documents, it just says "letter from the employer". They don't mention contracts. I was just wondering if this is truly enough in practice 