# Obtaining a visit visa to the UK for my wife

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, family

I'm looking for some general guidance on my wife's visa application.

I'm a British national who has been living in Pakistan for the past 3 years. I got married over 4 years ago to my wife, who is a Pakistani national. We had our first child in January of this year. I applied for my child's right of abode and that application was successful; the child has the right to enter and live in the UK as her father is a national.

Now my father is elderly and ill but would like to see his granddaughter. I have obtained a letter from the GP confirming he can't travel to Pakistan. I would like to apply for a 1 month visit visa for my wife. She has savings in her account and my brother has also sponsored her. So, proof of funding is not an issue.

The only issue I see is that they may reject the application of the grounds that she may not return after her visa expires, as me and the child are British. But, we are only planning on staying for 1 month and have no intentions of making the UK our permanent home for the time being. If I wanted to move my family to the UK, I would apply for a spouse visa and move over there.

Any idea on how the ECO would view this application? Am I likely to be rejected? How can I prove she will come back? Also, we made a visit for 8 days to Dubai on a family vacation.

Comment: You're right to be concerned; the spouse visa requirements are onerous, so the ECO will be alert to the possibility that you're trying to skirt these requirements.  Are you going to be going on this trip as well?

Comment: Yes, i am also travelling with them. when i was living and working in the uk i was earning more than enough to bring her over on a spouse visa. i can show wage slips and bank statements for that period

Comment: That should help.  Evidence of a successful and materially comfortable life in Pakistan since you've moved there will also help (and should be more influential, because if your life appears less comfortable now it might suggest to the ECO that you might want to return to your earlier life in the UK).

Comment: How should i show I'm happy living and earning in pakistan? bank statements? property documents?

Comment: I believe that is the standard way, yes.  Your wife would submit these as (part of) the evidence showing her current financial position.  But the UK also has a requirement to show that the money is coming from legitimate sources, so if it's income from business rather than employment I'd consider engaging a UK solicitor to prepare the application.   I would write a proper answer but I don't have time right now.  If nobody else does, I'll try to add one in the coming week.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55802/how-to-avoid-getting-a-visa-refusal-when-applying-for-a-uk-visitor-visa

Answer (score 2):

This [How to avoid getting a visa refusal when applying for a UK visitor visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55802/how-to-avoid-getting-a-visa-refusal-when-applying-for-a-uk-visitor-visa) covers pretty much everything you need to consider in order to prepare a solid application.

Provide a [cover letter](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-back-up-a-uk-visit-visa-appli) with your wife’s application that explains your own circumstances. Personally I would *not* make any comparison between your previous lifestyle in the UK and your economic situation now. Focus instead on stating the compelling reasons why you will all return to Pakistan at the end of the trip and providing evidence of ties to support that.

If you plan to stay with your father, you should provide an invitation letter from him confirming that he will accommodate you and your family for the duration of your visit [What should a sponsor tell the ECO?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69228/what-should-a-sponsor-tell-the-eco) A copy of your father’s passport should be included.

Finally, your question mentions that *“She has savings in her account and my brother has also sponsored her. So, proof of funding is not an issue.”* If that means your brother is helping her financially with the costs of the trip because *you* are not in a position to do so, then I do see a potential issue. A husband sponsoring his wife is completely normal. A brother sponsoring a sister is also common. However, a British citizen who is accompanying his wife on a visit to the UK but who isn’t covering the shortfall between his wife’s savings and the costs of the trip could be a red flag, IMHO.

Comment: I have funds in my bank but as me and my daughter are also travelling those funds are for me and her.

Comment: @ImranKhan Then I would definitely make that very clear in your covering letter, frame it as eg ‘total cost of the trip for the 3 of you is £x, of which £is being provided by your wife herself, £ from you, and £ from your brother. Having multiple financial sponsors makes things more complicated because you’ll need to prove the source of funds from each sponsor eg provide your brother’s bank statements and payslips. Also make sure that the amount you’re planning to spend on the trip is commensurate with your wife’s/your overall financial position (not spending **all** your savings, for example)