# How to show evidence of money being transferred from another account?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, bangladeshi-citizens

I am a Doctor from Bangladesh. I have passed PLAB 1 and going to apply for PLAB 2 visa which falls under the category of Standard Visitor visa. I am really worried because, as currently I am unemployed and working as a trainee Doctor in a hospital, my father is sponsoring me for my upcoming trip. He is a Government employee. His monthly salary is about £500. The problem is the bank statement he is going to show received a recent deposit of about £6,000.

Part of it (around £2,000) was transferred from my mother's savings account to his account and the rest of the money came from a car sale. I am going to show the documents for the car sale during the application.

But the problem is, how can I show that £2,000 which was transferred from another account?

Comment: Visa officials will be concerned about sudden unexpected deposits, especially if those deposits are used to fund the trip. If your father sold his car to sponsor your trip, that looks bad. If he can sponsor your trip even without those 6000 pounds, it looks better.

Comment: A copy of your mom's bank statement might prove that.

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51849/hidden-requirements-in-uk-visa-applications-source-of-evidence-of-funds/51863#51863