# UK Standard Visitor visa eligibility criteria

Tags: syrian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

I'm Syrian, I have an EU Student Residence Permit and soon I'll have an EU Working Residence Permit. I'm planning to visit London.

I need to have a [Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/eligibility). In applying, there are [four eligibility](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/eligibility) criteria I need to prove, which are:

1. You’ll leave the UK at the end of your visit
2. You’re able to support yourself and any dependents for the duration of your trip
3. You’re able to pay for your return or onward journey and any other costs relating to your visit
4. You have proof of any business or other activities you want to do in the UK, as allowed by the Visitor Rules

For the first point, I think it's enough to have the return ticket.

I don't think I need to do anything regarding the fourth point.

My questions are about the second and third points.

- Regarding the second point: how can I show that I'm able to *support myself and any dependents for the duration of your trip*?
- Regarding the third point: it has two things, first *pay for your return or onward journey*, which I can handle by showing the returning ticket, but what about *any other costs relating to your visit*?

I see that they're focusing mainly on being able to handle myself financially, how can I prove that?

I have a job from an EU country, would that be enough?

#### Update

I understand now that even for the first point, having the return ticket is not enough.

Comment: Having a ticket _does not_ demonstrate intent to leave the country. Anyone can buy a ticket to anywhere, after all.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  okay, so how can I prove that as well please ?

Comment: You are entertaining a disastrous fallacy about the eligibility criteria. Having an air ticket demonstrates capacity to have an air ticket and nothing else. Additionally they tell you straight up not to show them tickets. So you're not reading the criteria right. Also, I vaguely remember a Ministerial Order in effect for Syrian transit/visitor applicants but can't remember the details at the moment. I'll check.

Comment: @GayotFow Thanks, I got the idea that having the returning ticket doesn't demonstrate the intent to leave from the first comment, and I'm waiting for an answer for that criteria as well. Also, I've never heard of that Ministerial Order, appreciate it if you can find it.

Comment: Found it, it's HC1116, it doesn't apply to you. Also your assumption about point 4 is catastrophically out-of-whack, you should look at it again vis-a-vis your apparent lifestyle.  I updated the tags on your question so as to attract a wider audience of expertise.

Comment: @GayotFow thanks, kindly what about the 4th point? I'd like to visit London as a tourist, I don't have any business there.

Comment: They impute those things from your apparent lifestyle and personal circumstances. I am marking your question as a duplicate because you are asking how to prove you are eligible.  If you read the material and want your question reopened, you can edit your question for something specific.

Comment: Also, please read http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51849/hidden-requirements-in-uk-visa-applications-source-of-evidence-of-funds/51863#51863

Comment: @GayotFow thanks, sorry but may I ask you what did you mean by *impute those things from your apparent lifestyle and personal circumstances*? I'm asking because In one of your answers, you've written that being refused is not good even for the future when you have  better conditions. I'm about to finish my master in Portugal, I've been working in Portugal for 1 year, and soon I'm be moving to Amsterdam to work with another company. Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: @WilliamKinaan, you're an established user in the SE world so you would know we can't go on in comments. You can ping me from chat or ask an independent question.  Nice profile on the main site by the way