# Query regarding UK visa Application Dependent Details?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am filling the UK visa form for family visit. In form they have asked about Dependant details [Does anyone rely on you for financial support?
Include both those travelling with you and those who are not.] 
Does dependent means children or spouse as well. If person wife is house wife,  should she will be considered as dependent or not.
The other question is if child lives with their parent but doing his own job, does he consider to be dependent or not.

Comment: Thanks for comment. So, it means both will consider as dependent.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a detailed answer here: [How does UK Visa application define a dependent?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76064/how-does-uk-visa-application-define-a-dependent)

Typically, a dependent is someone who relies on you for financial support. So a spouse who is a homemaker (doesn’t have a job outside the home or other independent means). A child who is employed can also be classed as financially dependent eg if they live with their parent(s) but don’t contribute anything to the household budget, or just pay for food but not accommodation