# UK visa refused do to lack of economic ties in the UK. What are my options?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

Based on advice given on the forum. I have applied and was refused and below is the wordings of my refusal word for word.

> the decision
>
> I have refused your application for a visit visa
>   because i am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of
>   paragraphs V4.2 (a)(e). of appendix V. Immigration Rules for Visitors
>   because: Home Office records show that you have previously been
>   refused a UK visa. However each application has to be accessed based
>   on its merits using info and evidence submitted.
>
> You are seeking entry into UK for 8 days to visit your
>   family(MOTHER, father, bro)...who are all resident in UK. I note you
>   also have a sister in UK.
>
> You have stated on your application that you are employed as a
>   business development Exec with Snug Global Services and earn ***** per
>   month. You have supplied an employment letter to support this. I note
>   that this letter doesn't have a named signatory. The contact email for
>   the business is ********@gmail.com rather than an official, corporate
>   email account. I also note the phone numbers provided are mobile
>   numbers. A search through open sources has located an official website
>   for a business called ******* in Nigeria, however the contact details
>   on this website doesn't correspond with the details of the letterhead.
>   From the information on your application form and the documents you
>   have submitted, I am not satisfied that your employment and income is
>   as stated. I am therefore not satisfied that your economic status is
>   as declared.
>
> As evidence of funds you have submitted statements of  ****bank and
>   F*** bank for accounts in your name. However you have not sufficiently
>   documented your employment or your income and the documents supplied
>   support the origin of these funds. I am therefore not satisfied that
>   these funds are genuinely available for your use or that your
>   financial circumstances are as stated.
>
> Given the above I am not satisfied that your economic circumstances
>   are settled and that they constituent ties that tend to support your
>   stated intention to leave the UK.
>
> In the light of all the above I am not satisfied as to your intentions
>   in wishing to travel to the UK or that you will leave the UK at the
>   end of your visit. Furthermore I am not satisfied that you have
>   sufficient funds available to cover your costs whilst in the UK with
>   working or accessing public funds. Your application has been refused
>   under paragraph v 4.2(a)(e).

The copy of my employment letter was not signed by me (this was a stupid omission on my part). The original is on my file with the company.

My question is how do I show company and my employment letter is real and what documents should be submitted to address the ECO's concerns so as not to damage my credibility.

The company is registered with CAC, and the company does have an official email address which is not on the letterhead I submitted.

The mobile phone numbers was used to register the company with the CAC, so will showing company registration and company bank statement correct the wrong impression. What can the company I work for send to support my reapplication?

Comment: How do i address the ECO's concerns about company being unreal

Comment: The ECO was not concerned about the company being unreal. He was not satisfied that _your employment letter_ was real, and apparently with very good reason.

Comment: So how do i address this problem.

Comment: Is your employer actually the search result company?

Comment: When I was working I got a document for each pay period that showed my gross pay, deductions, and net pay. The gross pay matched my employment letter salary with documented adjustments such as bonuses. The net pay matched a simultaneous deposit to my bank account. Can you demonstrate that sort of salary to net pay to bank deposit match?

Comment: You should not be signing the letter from the company. A HR rep or manager including their job title should be signing it on official letterhead.

Comment: You never told us there was a history! That may have had an effect on the answers you received.  Why didn't you tell us????

Comment: @gayot fow..I told you i was refused awhile back but i didnt know precisely why i was refused.it was in 2009.i was in school way back then and i was sponsored by my mum in the UK. and i stated this in the cover letter precisely.

Comment: @patricia shanahan...yes the search result company is the same ..the official email address on the website isn"t on the letterhead.....the website was created 2years ago and the letterhead used was for local correspondences which is why it did not carry official email address

Comment: @gayot...Yes there were some unexplained deposits(i provided documentation for some of them) but i did not pad my account.Can company release a copy of bank statement of the account from which my salary is being deducted from?

Comment: I have nothing useful to say here, except that "and F*** bank" looks like a censored expletive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was a combination of issues that led to the refusal.

Starting with the employment letter:

> You have supplied an employment letter to support this. I note that
>   this letter doesn't have a named signatory.

To which you replied:

> The copy of my employment letter was not signed by me (this was a stupid omission on my part). The original is on my file with the company.

Normally such a letter in support of an application has the following, is written on company letterhead, and is signed by an authorized signatory (for example, the head of human resources, the CEO, etc.):

1. Your name (as in your passport)
2. Your identification details (for example, your passport or government id number)
3. Your position in the company (job title)
4. The length of your employment (for example, it shows your start date).
5. Your total salary

It also usually contains an indemnity clause.

In all cases, this letter is not supposed to be signed by you (I think you may have confused this with an *offer of employment* which is not the same thing).

You are also supposed to submit originals, or certified copies.

Next, the ECO tried to verify your employer is a genuine, legitimate business; and that did not go well either:

> The contact email for the business is ********@gmail.com rather than
>   an official, corporate email account. I also note the phone numbers
>   provided are mobile numbers. A search through open sources has located
>   an official website for a business called ******* in Nigeria, however
>   the contact details on this website doesn't correspond with the
>   details of the letterhead.

Next, the officer tried to validate your means of support during the application, and there were some issues there as well:

> As evidence of funds you have submitted statements of ****bank and
>   F*** bank for accounts in your name. However you have not sufficiently
>   documented your employment or your income and the documents supplied
>   support the origin of these funds. I am therefore not satisfied that
>   these funds are genuinely available for your use or that your
>   financial circumstances are as stated.

The ECO is saying that in your bank statements, it is not clear or obvious that your salary is being deposited, or what is the other source of the funds. As it is not clear (to the ECO) the source and nature of these funds, he/she is not satisfied that you are authorized to use these funds.

In summary:

1. The letter you supplied stating your employment was not signed by anyone.
2. The company details on the letterhead didn't match publicly available information on the company's website.
3. Your bank statements didn't show regular income as proof of the funds you had.

All these combined led to the rejection of your application. The fact that you were rejected before is on file, but each application is judged separately.

Now, what can you do?

I suggest the following; but nothing is guaranteed here, I am just stating from my experience dealing with visa applications. Even if you do all this, your application may still be rejected:

1. Show official payslips. Normally, companies deposit salaries into bank accounts directly (wire transfer, direct deposit, etc.) and issue regular payslips which show your earnings and any deductions for that period. If you are being paid in cash - then you will have a tougher time with this.
2. Provide independent evidence of the existence of the company; however normally such documentation is not necessary as company information is usually public. In your case, the companies details are in question which raises immediate red flags. Therefore, I would try to provide some third party supporting documents. These could be in the form of a letter from the chamber of commerce or business registry, a copy of the business license (which is properly notarized), etc. or a letter from your company's law firm.
3. Your bank account should correspond to your income. Do not borrow funds to pad your account. If you have any unexplained deposits (for example, a separate bonus) these should be explained if on the bank statement the narrative is not obvious.

---

See also: [My application was refused due to 'lack of evidence of funds', are there hidden requirements for UK visa applications?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51849/hidden-requirements-in-uk-visa-applications-source-of-evidence-of-funds) for other tips

Comment: the issue is the online website for the company had an official e-mail address.but that official email address didnt appear on the letterhead for my employment letter.And Yes the CEO did not sign,it was signed by HR manager,but the online website had the CEO details.,,so can i show a new letter signed by the CEO with his passport data page attached,,The CEO has travelled alot and has valid UK visa and US visa.The company is registered with CAC and it can be verified.Company sends wire transfer into employee accounts from company account

Comment: Yes there were some unexplained deposits(i provided documentation for some of them) but i did not pad my account.Can company release a copy of bank statement of the account from which my salary is being deducted from?

Comment: what document apart from the employment letter should the company release to prove i am their employee

Comment: The fact that the CEO has traveled a lot does not help your case. Bank statements can only be released by banks, not companies. Your employer's bank account statement is not relevant here. You don't need an employment letter, you need a salary certificate.

Comment: ,.Yes the company can request for a bank statement from the bank and i can along with the application to prove that im an employee with the company much i get paid monthly..Whats a salary certificate?

Comment: A salary certificate is a document that shows your details, length of employment and your total salary. It is a fairly common document. I am not sure if it is called something else Nigeria.

Comment: @burhan...never heard of that here..whats the difference between salary certificate and one's employment letter.

Comment: Your employment letter is what gets you the job; the salary certificate lets others know that you are employed; because its states your title, length of employment, salary, etc.

Comment: @burhan..i dont think i have heard of that here...what other documents do u think i can drop to reapply

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43913/discussion-between-adek-and-burhan-khalid).