# UK Standard Visitor Visa refusal for lack of ties... how should I reapply?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, ghanaian-citizens

I applied for a UK visit visa to attend a British Army assessment which provided me with two dates, the first on 20-22 February and the second in March. I stated clearly in my visa application my total a monthly income and the amount I spend every month. However, on my refusal letter, it was stated that I "declared no income."

I also submitted a letter from my school and a permission letter to attend the British Army assessment. I used these to show my strong ties to my country but, it seems, that was overlooked.

What can I do to improve my next application so that I can attend the assessment in March?

[image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question grabbed my curiosity enough that I've checked your previous questions. Namely, you've asked a [question about, I think, this application which has a lot of relevant information](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86634/what-more-should-i-add-when-applying-for-a-standard-visitor-visa-to-attend-briti).

You were refused under [paragraph 4.2 points a and c](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules#part-v4-eligibility-requirements-for-visitors-standard) which means that he didn't believe that you are a genuine visitor and that you will leave the UK at the end of your visit. In human terms, this means that ECO thinks that it's likely that once you hit the British soil, you will go underground.

While you have declared income of 150 pounds on your application, it's source isn't clear and unless you have provided clarification of how is that income (and from the previous post it doesn't seem to be the case), it most likely will be seen as you being dependent on your family. Your only solid tie seems to be the university course, but that alone is usually not enough.

If you want to pursue with another application, then your best course of action is to seek a solicitor or a seasoned adviser to write up your next application and center it around a military career in your close family, which would explain your reasons a bit better. Seeking a career in the military in your home country could go a long way too, as it would explain the sudden urge to join an army.

Comment: +1, great answer from a noob and we celebrate your moving up the ranks. Please continue to do that.  I emphatically suggest that you edit your answer to remove Gayot's link. It's unnecessary and your answer can stand independently without it. Please edit. And again, congrats on a great answer!

Comment: @GayotFow thank you for the kind words! I've amended it accordingly, and hope that next one will be better :).

Answer (score 18):

You applied for a Standard Visitor Visa to attend an assessment session in the UK with the British Army. You are a student, are not working, have no dependants and entirely rely on your father to fund this trip.

Hate to break it to you, but at this point your chances of joining the British Army are slim.

The simple fact is that they want to see that **you** are able to support yourself while in the UK, without engaging in illegal employment. Almost invaribly, this has to be shown through several consecutive bank statements **of your own**. Furthermore, they want to see that you have family or financial ties making you able to say "this is why I **have** to go back home"

If you're serious about wanting to join the British Army, your father will have to pay for a qualified immigration solicitor. [This website](https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/) provides a good starting point. If you're lucky, they may tell you there is a way to secure a visa. In this case, co-operate with them and follow their advice ***scrupulously***, because again, your current circumstances are **not** in your favour.

On the bright side: in another question you mentioned having three sisters who are British soldiers. Did you mention that when applying? If not, you **definitely** need to explain it to whatever solicitor you hire, and put it forth in the application in a very specific way that only a solicitor will be able to do correctly. If it becomes clear that being a soldier is a credible choice of career for you, your credibility as an applicant *could* massively increase. However, this is by **no** means a guarantee.

Good luck!

Comment: @EthanElisha I emphatically recommend you to wait for another user named Gayot Fow to answer, since he is **the** expert on UK visas. But yeah, these are my two pennies.

Comment: ,sure then I would wait for him to comment so I take not of that in my next application

Comment: @Crazydre don't wait for Gayot, this answer is fine AS IS.

Comment: @EthanElisha he is not going to comment, this answer and the other one are fine

Comment: @EthanElisha Welp, in that case, upvote and accept (button below the down arrow) whichever answer you feel most satisfied with