# British Army Invitation to assessment center from Jamaica

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, jamaican-citizens

I'm a Jamaican and was recently invited to the army assessment center. What type of visa should I apply for and what documents I'm going to need?......I'd also like to know the length of stay I should use when applying.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. While not an exact duplicate, Gayot Fow's answer in *[What more should I add when applying for a Standard Visitor visa to attend British Army assessment?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86634/)* provides information that should be useful to you.

Comment: Use the search box (at the top of each SE:Travel page) for "British Army Assessment." A list of previous questions on this subject will be returned. Unfortunately, the quality of a good army candidate (i.e., one who can easily move from country of origin and not return), and the quality of a good candidate for a UK visa (i.e., one who has ties and will return to country of origin) are in conflict, which makes a visa for assessment purposes difficult to obtain.

Answer (score 1):

The [GOV](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/armed-forces-arf/armed-forces-arf--2#arf43-how-do-applicants-enter-the-uk-to-enlist-in-hm-forces) website provides some information on this:

> ## 7. ARF4.3 How do applicants enter the UK to enlist in HM Forces?
>
> From 11 July 2013 the Ministry of Defence requires all Commonwealth nationals seeking to enlist in HM Forces to demonstrate that they have lived in the UK with valid leave for a minimum of 5 years immediately prior to commencing the recruitment process.
>
> The only exceptions to this requirement will be those individuals who hold evidence from the Ministry of Defence dated prior to 11 July 2013 of either:
>
> - a written valid job offer,
>     confirmation of a training place,
> - a confirmed date to attend an assessment centre, or
> - a confirmed date to attend a psychometric test (RAF and Navy only).
>
> Applications from those seeking entry to the UK solely on the basis that they are either seeking to commence or progress through the recruitment process will fall to be refused unless the residency requirement is met.
>
> For example, students who have previously held lawful leave and studied in the UK for over five years but have recently returned home for a short holiday may qualify if they have obtained one of the
>   documents outlined in the above paragraph whilst in the UK.
>
> Once the applicant has been enlisted into HM Forces, they should submit their passport to us with a covering note from the military unit - no application form is required. When submitted, the passport of the person should be endorsed with suspension of any limited leave to enter or remain.

Comment: the answer above is no longer correct. the residency requirement was lifted in november 2018.

Comment: Have you a citation to support the assertion that residency is no longer required?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica The Army recruitment site states there is no residency requirement for Commonwealth nationals https://apply.army.mod.uk/how-to-join/can-i-join/nationality

Comment: @Traveller Thanks, that's more directly applicable to the OP and more recent info than the site linked-to below. It's worth noting, however, that "no residency requirement" does _not_ mean that a Commonwealth candidate is exempt from securing a visa to travel to the UK to take the assessment.