# Reapplying as an Unemployed

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-ties

[image]
I want to know if I can reapply after visa refusal on a different account which is based on unemployed.. Since I put part time worker in the previous application would my new status in my new application affect me..

Comment: You can reapply again but you will just be refused again, and if you intend to employ deception on the application, you will likely be banned. See the linked post above for an explanation of why you were actually refused and what you can do.

Comment: You may also wish to search this site for British Army Assessment, as many other people have tried to enter the UK for a similar reason and also been refused.

Comment: I think the answer to https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/140301/819 , while not addressing this question, appears very relevant to your situation.

Comment: What do you mean "a different account which is based on unemployed?" If you told them you're employed part-time, and now you tell them you're unemployed, they'll either think you lied the first time about having a part-time job, or they'll think you quit or lost your job. Neither is good. It doesn't sound like your circumstances are such that you're likely to get a visa at this time.

Comment: Thank you so much guys for the information, I thought I should clear my head since I was really bothered.. Am fine now.. Am greatful.. I'll just have to reapply when I get a standard job.