# What do I need to apply for a UK visa

Tags: international-travel, london

I am a Jamaican who lives and works for the government as an educator in Japan. I would like to travel to the UK for several reasons.

1. Even though I have a 10 year U.S. visa, as a black woman, I do not feel safe staying in the U.S. at this time.
2. I have a friend I haven't seen for years who lives in London
3. I need to buy a wedding dress and some clothing items, unfortunately Japan doesn't cater to curvy women

I am nervous about the application process because it is rumored that Jamaicans have a hard time. So here are my questions

1. Should the amount shown in my bank account reflect the cost of my stay in London, as well as the airfare and hotel costs?
2. I'd like to pass through the UK to go to Jamaica for 5 days, and then an additional  4 days in London, should my bank account reflect the amount for my trip to Jamaica as well?

Comment: see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105  1. Preferably YES 2. Preferably YES. But bank statements mean a lot more. Don't PARK (http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51849/my-application-was-refused-due-to-lack-of-evidence-of-funds-are-there-hidden/51863#51863) money in your account for this trip.