# Do I need my own bank account to apply for a United Kingdom visa?

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am a businessman. I am running my company. I wish to apply for a UK Visitor Visa for holiday vacations. I do not have a personal bank account, only the company account. May I apply now using the bank statements from the company account?

Comment: I want to ask without personal bank statement, Can I Apply with Company's bank accounts?

Comment: You need your own bank account. You should separate your personal and your business accounts, draw a salary or other pay from the company, and retain your pay slips.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas that's good for an answer, you can tart it up into one in a jiffy.

Comment: @GayotFow - done, though I'm unsure if there is any official publication or direction to support my statements.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas +1, it's a great answer. You have the right links etc etc. v nice

Answer (score 8):

You need a **personal** bank account when applying for a UK visitor visa. This account should contain your *personal* funds, which are separate from your *company's* funds. You cannot rely on your company account's bank statements because they do not represent money that is *only for your use*. (The money is the company's; conceivably it would be used for payroll, business expenses, equipment, etc.)

What you should do is as follows:

1. Open a personal bank account.
2. Start drawing a salary/dividends on a regular basis from your company.
3. Deposit this salary into your personal account.
4. Retain your pay slips as a record of your earnings.

After some time, you can apply for the UK visa and submit your *personal* bank account statements, along with your payslips.

While this seems like a case of just moving money around, it is important to distinguish between yourself as a person, and your employer as a company. Even when you own your company, you are an employee of that company. Your pay slips will serve to prove the [provenance of *your* funds](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/51863/3161) -- where it came from, how you got it, taxes have been paid, etc., and that it is entirely legal.

---

For more information, please refer to the following question:

- [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

---

<sub>Keeping your business and personal funds separate is also a good business practice, though out-of-scope for this site.</sub>