# UK Tourist visa refused the second time

Tags: visa-refusals

[image]I received my first refusal on 13th November 2017 stating that I have an unexplainable transfer of credit on 8/10/2017.

On my second application I have attached the refusal letter and addressed it. The unexplainable credit transfer made was actually from my credit card as I am allowed to borrow 95% from my credit limit.I have attached the letter to prove source of funds together with bank statement and credit card statement it was refused again. In the refusal letter, the ECO stated that 'from the documents you have submitted it does not show your credit card bank statement. It does not demonstrate where these funds are from.'

I went back to the visa application center(VFS GLOBAL QATAR) but they said whatever documents we submit, they are forwarding to UKVI and that they cannot show me the documents which they have submitted on my behalf. It is disappointing as I have paid an additional amount for their priority service.

Is UKVI having some errors sometimes? I am sure that I have submitted my credit card bank statement to justify the transferred credit with stamp and signature from the bank.

Thank you for anyone who would take time to read and answer.

Comment: Please post a photo of the refusal letter with your personal details blanked out. This will help people on here give you accurate answers.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you charged your credit card (basically a cash advance) so you could show more money in your bank account?

Comment: @mkennedy Yes I did, but on my first application I wasn't able to attach any justification. On my second attempt I have applied a personal loan from my bank amounting to 4,000 GBP, addressed the uncertainties raised in previous rejection letter, attached credit card statement, bank statement and loan contract.

Comment: @user16259 Thank you, the refusal letter is below.

Answer (score 4):

To make the long story short you cannot afford the suggested vacation and loan doesn't change it.

Before card transfer, you had about 2k GBP in your account altogether, and cost of your trip is 3k while you earn 1,2k a month before paying taxes, rent, food, utilities etc. That means you plan to spend 3 full months worth of salary just to come and sightsee the UK for 2 weeks. That alone already is going to raise all sort of bells.

But to make the matters worse you didn't even save up 3k, instead it looks like sizeable part of your trip comes from credit, and generally speaking, credit comes with interest. So the 3k trip, that already was a financial stretch, now also will cost you interest payments on the balance when you come back. Most people who travel don't do that, and you will have to have one hell of an explanation for the ECO to explain why are the 2 weeks in the UK so important to you.

Comment: why didn’t they just state that from their refusal letter. I had a friend who did the same thing, he even borrowed twice the amount of what I have borrowed. It’s a small amount of money to be paid from my salary monthly. They did not inform people from their rules or guidelines that you cannot have a personal loan to spend for your trip.

Comment: @Mavi Your position would be a lot stronger if you had ample supply of savings and didn't need to bleed it dry + get a loan to fund two weeks of vacation. And if you will read the second point of refusal it states "Furthermore I am not satisfied that you have sufficient funds available to cover your costs..." which indicates that your personal finances are going to be a problem. You may want to read this answer to get a better view of the issue: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51849/my-application-was-refused-due-to-lack-of-evidence-of-funds-are-there-hidden

Comment: @Mavi actually this link: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: @Mavi The last link  is one of the best answers in Travel.SE and explains in detail what the immigration people want to see and what they don't want to see. Your application is in this view senseless because *you do not have the money to travel to the UK*. And the immigration officer does not tell you the reason because he does not want you to circumvent or trick the system.

Comment: Yeah, so they’ve just stated something in the refusal letter and not tell people straight to the point, if they did, I shouldn’t have reapplied and spent more money on it. Thank you for the answer, if I’ll receive a refusal again, I’ll stop and try next year.

Comment: Thank you for the links, I’ll read it carefully and will apply again next year hopefully! Cheers!