# Spouse visa- Do I need a home surveyor?

Tags: visas, accommodation, uk-citizens, spouses

I am legally married to my wife from the states- we will be doing the spouse visa in April.

I was wondering if I need a home surveyors report or can I just write down the location I am living, the bedrooms, the dimensions of the room, information about all the people that living there with a signature from a lawyer confirming everything about the house situation? I would also include a letter from the landlord giving permission to live there with a copy of the deed of the house.

I know a lawyer who is happy to sign for us at a cheaper price whereas a home surveyor is charging much more.

Would this work?

Edit: as indicated in OP earlier questions, he is a British citizen, his wife is a US citizen and they have been married for 1 1/2 years, if not more, as they were at the time of his October 2016 query.

My apologies- to clarify, I am a british citizen- I was born here.We have been married religiously since nov 2015 but only legalised the marriage in april 2017- we are wishing to carry out a spouse visa.

Comment: This would probably be better suited to the [Expatriates SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions), and you should specify which country you're referring to.

Comment: Is your wife coming to live with you or just visit? If the former, this belongs on [Expatriates.SE], as noted by brhans.  As also noted by brhans, we have no way of knowing from your question as it currently stands what country you live in, so we cannot know the requirements for a spouse visa in that country.

Comment: Weekday country are we talking about?

Comment: It sounds like you want to bring your wife to live with you, but you didn't say what country you are living in. Are you a citizen there? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I've never heard of a formal home survey by a surveyor as a requirement for a spousal visa - can you explain why you think you might need one?

Comment: Yes, sorry- I am a british citizen. There was a blog online helping with all the things which one should include in a spouse visa- one of the topics covered was accomodation.

I only think I may need one since the visa requires proof of accomodation and the blog which provided information suggested a home surveyor to show whether or not the I am renting is overcrowded perhaps? or if it is suitable.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a requirement, but is among the options, according to the UKVI* [guide to supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/270197/sup-docs-settlement.pdf)

> **Accommodation details**
>
> You may wish to submit any of the following documents to provide us with evidence of your accommodation. We advise that you do not make any payments for accommodation, travel and so on until you have received your visa.
>
> Details of the accommodation that you and your sponsor intend to live in and permission for you to stay there along with evidence of any other occupants
>
> This could include:
>
> - Land Registry documents
> - mortgage statements
> - rent book or tenancy agreement
> - council tax statements
> - property inspection report
> - utilities bills
> - accommodation details with a supporting letter from the occupant/ landlord confirming that you are able to stay there

The [Housing Act 1985 Part II](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1985/68) covers provision of housing accommodation. It gives [overcrowding rules](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1985/68/part/X) and defines what exactly is a bedroom and how many people can occupy it. The overcrowding analysis can be done by a licensed surveyor. In most instances, ECO's take the applicant's word for it.

And while the question is not applicable, [this response by @GayotFow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51849/my-application-was-refused-due-to-lack-of-evidence-of-funds-are-there-hidden) has quite a bit of valuable feedback that can help guide you..

*While the linked pdf bears UK Border Agency logo, now UK Visa & Immigration, the content originally published in 2013 has been maintained and updated, most recently in October 2017.