# Bank statement UK visitor visa

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens, pakistan, proof-provenance-of-funds

ECO concerned with opening balance of bank statement ? My statement of account is consistent and there is no funds Parking . Can he refuse application by simply stating how you got money ?
 My monthly income is 50 thousand pkr and opening balance of my statement is 1.3 million which I collected by selling a car last year and it is my saving in my account .. much confused and need positive opinion please

Comment: The *opening balance* was on which date?

Comment: I have to provide previous 6 months statement..right ? My opening balance is 1.3 million which is from almost one year back and 50k/month in shape of salary

Comment: @user61594 Notwithstanding the time lapse, to the ECO your balance probably looked totally out of line with your income. Can you provide provenance as to the source of the funds? Eg car ownership transfer document?

Comment: Nope. If you have had 1.3 million for 6 months the funds are

Comment: @greatone so I should not hesitate to apply if conditions other than Bank statement are fulfilled

Comment: @user61594 The Home Office Visit Guide does not specifically state the period of time bank statements should cover. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673351/Visit-guidance-v7.0EXT.PDF#page15

Comment: @Traveller I should wirhdraw half million?  or keep all as I am keeping for almost an year ..

Comment: @user61594 Have you actually had a refusal (if so, please upload the notice, with your personal information redacted)? My point is that 1.3m is out of line with your income, so in my opinion it would be better if the ECO could see when the money arrived in your account and from where, otherwise it could be a red flag. If you’ve not yet submitted your application then if I were you I’d explain and provide evidence, I wouldn’t do anything with my bank account now simply to try to improve my chances of getting a visa.

Comment: @Traveller I was refused visa during may 2017 for funds Parking and other reason . I had sold CAR and put that money in my account and resultantly my account jumped up sale deed was attached with application but ECO took it other way and refused my application . Now I am keeping those funds since previous unsuccessful application and want to re apply .. Now I font know what will be the consequences of keeping such money in my account while it is clearly my savings ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Can he refuse application by simply stating how you got money?**

The ECO can refuse the application if the provenance of funds is unclear.

A typical phrase in a refusal letter would be

> I am not satisfied you have demonstrated that your circumstances are as you claim and therefore I am not satisfied that you're travelling to the UK for the period and purpose you stated.

See

- [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) - especially the section on "Provenance of funds" in the top answer.
- [UK Visa Refusal: Provenance of funds/parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39153/13639)
- [My application was refused due to 'lack of evidence of funds', are there hidden requirements for UK visa applications?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/51849/13639)
- [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66104/13639)

---

> **opening balance of my statement is 1.3 million which I collected by selling a car last year and it is my saving in my account**

I expect you need to provide evidence of the sale. If the original acquisition of the car by you was not commensurate with your normal income, it may help to explain how this came about.

> **I should wirhdraw half million?**

If you do anything just to make your bank statements look better to the ECO, she may conclude you are being deceptive - which is grounds for refusal.

Mysterious movements of large sums make your application more difficult to support.