# Questions before applying for UK visa and Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, europe, tourist-visas

I'm an Indonesian citizen who is planning to apply for a UK visa and a Schengen visa. I have also lived in the United States since 2012 so I'm a legal US permanent resident with valid green card and state ID. I'm currently a full-time college student but planning on taking a semester off to travel to the UK and some countries in Europe.

Because I'm going to school full-time, I only work part-time. My dad who still lives in Indonesia has been supporting me and will also be doing so for my planned trip so I have some questions:

1) I will submit my bank statement but will it be okay if I also submit my dad's bank statement, even though he lives in another country?

- Along with his bank statement, I will also have him go to a notary and sign an affidavit of support and I will also give them his contacts in Indonesia to proof that he is indeed my father.
- I definitely want to do this to avoid 'funds parking'.

2) The UK requires people from Indonesia to have a TB test but I have been a legal residence of the United States for six years, will I be required to get one as well?

I will apply for the Schengen visa at the Italian Consulate General in Houston and the UK visa by mailing all of my documents to the UK embassy in D.C.

Comment: If your father is sponsoring your trip financially then you should not only submit his bank statements but also evidence of the source of his funds eg employment contract, pay slips. You only need a TB test if you plan on visiting the UK for more than 6 months and are a resident of Indonesia https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/tuberculosis-test-for-a-uk-visa-clinics-in-indonesia/tuberculosis-testing-in-indonesia

Answer (score 0):

If your father is sponsoring your trip to the UK financially then you should not only submit his bank statements (3-6 months) but also evidence of the source of the funds eg employment contract, payslips [My application was refused due to 'lack of evidence of funds', are there hidden requirements for UK visa applications?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51849/my-application-was-refused-due-to-lack-of-evidence-of-funds-are-there-hidden) Indonesian citizens visiting the UK only need a TB test for trips longer than 6 months and if they are resident in Indonesia. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/tuberculosis-test-for-a-uk-visa-clinics-in-indonesia/tuberculosis-testing-in-indonesia However, if you’ve visited home frequently in the recent past it may be an idea to check with your local UK embassy.

Comment: I have only visited home once ever since I moved to the United States six years ago so I'm a permanent resident of the U.S. I will definitely email the U.K. Embassy in the United States to ask if they will accept a foreign bank statement. Thank you for your advice!