# How should I answer the following 'income and expenditure' question on the UK standard visitor visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I am a Pakistani citizen living in Denmark, who will be travelling to the UK on the 26th of September to help my daughter settle in for university. I will be returning to Denmark on the 29th of September. My husband, who is a Danish citizen owns a restaurant and I work as the chef helper there, and earn a total of 5000 dkk per month, which gets transferred to my husbands' account since we both share our income to pay the household bills, food, leisure activities, etc (he obviously earns more than me). So basically, I am quite unsure as to how I should be answering the following Income and Expenditure question on the application:

1. What is the total amount of money you spend each month?

I earn approx 5000 per month. However, I do use my husband's private master card to buy food, pay the rent, electricity bill etc. Is the question asking me, as to how much I spend off of 'my' money each month or is it asking me to quote the general amount of money we spend as on ourselves as a family (we also have three kids who don't work and are completely dependent on my husband's mastercard to pay for their expenses). Or should I only quote 5000 kr since that is the amount I get paid each month?

Sorry if I sound confusing, I am in fact very confused.

Comment: The point of these questions is to allow UKVI to assess whether the cost of the trip is within an applicant’s means and proportionate to their financial situation. If I were you I’d state your personal income and your ‘share’ of the family expenditure plus your own spending, assuming that a) that adds up to less than your income; and b) your husband doesn’t finance your expenses. You can provide further explanation, if needed, in the ‘comments’ section at the end of the application or in a covering letter

Comment: @Traveller Oh alright! Does that mean that I should simply divide the family expenditure by 5? (Assuming I do not have any personal spending.) Since we are 5 people in the household? The cost of the trip came out to 7000 dkk (which I may be personally spending), however, my husband has allowed me to use 10,000 dkk on this trip (I will be using his private mastercard to pay for all expenses during the 3 ish day trip including flights, accommodation, food, and other living expenses-as I always do in Denmark anyways).

Comment: Effectively then, you can demonstrate your income to UKVI (payslips) but unless you have funds in a separate account in your own name, you can’t easily show that you can afford the trip out of your own resources, therefore your husband is partially sponsoring the cost. Is that correct? If so, this question might help https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51849/my-application-was-refused-due-to-lack-of-evidence-of-funds-are-there-hidden and this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e

Comment: @Traveller Just 1 more question! So, for the part where I have to mention as to why my husband is paying for the trip, I provided the following answer: ''My income gets transferred into my husband's private bank account, since we combine our income to pay for the family's expenses. My husband and I use my husband's private credit card to pay for the entire family's (us two and our three kids) household and living expenses. I thereby will be taking this credit card with me, and will be using it for all costs that arise during this short trip to the UK (Since this is what I do in Denmark).''

Comment: @Traveller Are you sure that's what they're looking for? I mean you could easily be earning a good wage in your own country but living with your parents and thus zero costs per month. Your own earnings would just be used for fun and savings. That's really common in my country in fact, but in the question they don't allow zero as an answer but it obviously could easily be zero.

Comment: @Hasen In that case, you would declare the amount you spend on ‘fun’, so the answer is unlikely ever to be zero.