# Can I expect to get a UK visa if I was refused under v14 and v4.2a,c?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I had US (B1/B2) visa and I wanted to set up LLC in the US to run my own start-up. I had created LLC and received my EIN through the internet. The next step is to open business account in one of the US banks. So, I intended visit the US by that visa to open my account.

I decided to fly through UK because I already had UK visa before and visited UK. It was the shortest path for me. I had to get transit visa.

Unfortunately, there was a really big delay in UK consulate (almost 9 weeks) and my US visa expired during that period. They sent me email with recommendations to withdraw my application. But I thought "what if I would get UK visa first and then get new US visa to speed up the process?" **Yes, it was a mistake .** But I didn't realize it in time.

So, I received the notification about refusal. There are 3 points.

> • In support of your travel intentions, I have received your email confirming the change of
> travel dates to August 2024. Whilst I have noted the flight tickets for the initial travel
> planned in December 2023, there is no demonstration of purchased tickets for
> rescheduled visit in August 2024. Since the onus is on you to provide supporting
> information and documents and to demonstrate your travel intentions are genuine, I am
> not satisfied you are genuinely going to travel to the country of destination, the USA in
> the stated period.

> • Furthermore, I have noted your visitor visa for the USA is due to expire on 19 January
> 2024. I have acknowledged your statements you intend to request a new visa for the
> newly proposed travel dates. However as such, I am not satisfied you are assured entry
> to your country of destination, the USA.

> • You have stated that you are self-employed in the Game and Software Development. In
> support of your current personal and financial circumstances you have enclosed the
> supporting documents demonstrating a newly registered company in the USA, and the
> clarifications that you do not have any earnings yet since it is a start-up. Whilst I have
> noted the bank statement from the mBank in Poland on your name confirming available
> funds of $... (£... at the current exchange rate on [www.oanda.com](http://www.oanda.com)) , there
> is no further information about your current source of income, how you are supported in
> Poland or Belarus, and how you have accumulated demonstrated funds. As a result, I
> am not satisfied you have demonstrated your personal and economic circumstances in
> full, as a true, accurate and credible portrayal of your current situation or that they are as such that you can be relied upon to meet the requirements of entry clearance.

I was surprised about the first one because I provided flight numbers to the officer for my traveling. They are real. I also have flight tickets. I thought the oficer will ask me to provide them too(because there was a recomendation do not by flight tickets untill got a visa), but he didn't. Anyway, it is what it is.

Could somebody provide some ideas?

**Update**

A few sentences from the letter I received telling about my refusal. It's said It seems I need transit visa because I am Belarus citizen(correct me if I misinterpreted it please)

REASONS FOR REFUSAL NRA v 1.0
You are a national/citizen of a country or territorial entity specified in Schedule 1 to the Immigration (Passenger Transit Visa) Order 2014 (as amended). Such persons seeking to pass through the United Kingdom on route to another country or territory without entering the United Kingdom require a transit visa.

Comment: v14 is not a thing AFAIK

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Sorry, could you elaborate more?

Comment: v14 is not a UK Visa refusal reason, v4.2 a and c are

Comment: But I have a text in my letter 'Your application is therefore refused under Paragraph V14 and V4.2 (a), (c) of Appendix V of the Immigration Rules.'

Comment: Yeah, that may be a typo (weird), but either way your questions are probably answered by [My application was refused due to 'lack of evidence of funds', are there hidden requirements for UK visa applications?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51849/my-application-was-refused-due-to-lack-of-evidence-of-funds-are-there-hidden) and [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Comment: yes, thanks. I have already read one of them. But it says reasons what officers want to see. It still not clear where I could fix that issue and they may approve. Or that there is no chances at all... I will have a look at another one you shared

Comment: What to do to fix: get your US visa, and when/if you reapply to the UK provide paperwork to address refusal point #3.

Comment: Please upload a picture of your refusal letter, with any personal information blacked out.

Comment: This doesn't seem too bad.  The refusal reasons are all technical.  A well prepared application along the lines suggested in DJClayworth's answer should have a fair chance of success.

Comment: You could also just take a flight via Dubai or Istanbul to avoid the headache.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three things to do in order to fix the problems you are having - or maybe just one, depending on what you do.

**First**: get yourself a valid US visa for the time you want to visit. Not doing so was an elementary mistake. The UK will not issue a transit visa without knowing you are able to enter the country you are next stopping in. In fact getting a US visa may solve all your problems because **[owners of a valid US visa do not need a UK transit visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)** provided they don't have to clear UK immigration and depart within 24 hours of their arrival by a reasonable route.

If you find that for some reason you do need a transit visa then you should provide actual tickets for your journey. To get a transit visa you need to *prove* that you will depart within 24 hours of arrival from the same airport where you landed. A ticket is going to be the only way to do this. Quoting a flight number is not going to be enough.

Finally (if you do need a visa) you will need to provide sufficient details of your income, expenditure, and how you support yourself in your country of residence. A single statement is not sufficient. See [our question here about financial statements](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) for more details.

Comment: ok, thank you for the details. Actually, I need a transit visa. I naively believed that it would be enough to show my US visa and bank account with money...

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you need a transit visa if you have a US visa?

Comment: I am from Belarus. Since some moment in the past it is already need transit visa for those who are traveling to the US through UK. As far as I know...

Comment: Check this official website https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa. It says the Belarus citizens do not need a transit visa if they have a valid US visa. It's possible that something has changed recently, but I can't find anything that says that. Can you also please edit the question to say that you have Belarus citizenship.

Comment: Hm, probably you are right. I don't already remeber why exactly I decided to apply for this visa. But for what I see now, there are 2 concerns which would lead me to apply for the visa just in case:

1. There is sentence in the end when you get information about applying:
You will not be able to transit without a visa if a Border Force officer decides you do not qualify under the immigration rules. You can apply for a transit visa before you travel if you’re unsure whether you qualify for transiting without a visa.
2. Second reason is from letter I received. I've updated my first post

Comment: Actually, I have pretty big experience travelling through the border. So, I've got used to have as much evidence of my traveling as possible :)

Comment: Anyway, next time I will ask help from some agents :)

Comment: @serp If so make sure you only use an approved agent. There are a lot of scammers out there.